# Hang / Unreponsive Windows/GUI - VBA

Tags: vba

Is there a way to avoid hanging and unresponsiveness of windows while running inside vba code/macro on large data. At times I can't even move window from one position to another.
What is role of DoEvents in this case.
There is one particular case with Excel vba, where when macro is running and updating data in active sheet, gets stopped when user enters some text in active cell and presses enter.
Also, is this common, that, you can't work with other excel workbooks when one excel vba macro is running. I am experiencing this problem a lot.

Regards,

Comment: A faster machine may help... Depends really

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd> **or** <kbd>Break</kbd> should halt the code and enter the debug state.

Answer (score 0):

Office applications are single-threaded. If you perform excessive actions in VBA, this may cause the application to appear unresponsive to Windows, so Windows will create a white overlay on top of your application's window and add *[Not responding]* to the window caption.

*DoEvents* is basically telling the Windows message queue to process all messages that have accumulated since the last time the messages could be processed. If a process is idle, its messages are processed immediately, but if the process is very busy, the message queue may grow considerably, and processing it is postponed until the process comes back to idle state. Sometimes you can observe that all UI actions happen in a flash once that state is reached, like in a time lapse video. Really not desirable.
However, *DoEvents* needs to be used with care. It rarely solves any problem to just throw in some *DoEvents* code lines in arbitrary places.

Think of the poor users, too. If you have a process that takes more than just a few seconds, it is more than gentle to present a progress dialog with some info on how far the process has come, and how much is left to be done. This kills two birds with one stone. *DoEvents* serves a good purpose here. If you assign new captions to labels (e.g. a percentage of completion), or set the value property of a progress bar while your heavy-duty process runs, UI changes will not be reflected on the screen until the *DoEvents* command is issued (at least when your process is still underway). So you can use *DoEvents* to ensure the UI is updated regularly. For instance, if you are processing records from a very large table, update the progress information every 100 record(s) or so, and also ensure that DoEvents is issued eventually. The interval depends on how much time it takes to process a number of records. You should pick an interval that can be reached within a second to ensure that your progress info refreshes frequently enough. If the interval is too long, the application will again appear unresponsive.

Picking the right update interval will keep your UI from freezing up, and reduce user frustration as they get an idea how long they have left to wait. If you ensure the progress dialog is modal, then users won't have a chance to interfere by beginning to enter text in any cell until the process has finished. Because this is a very bad thing to happen. Beginning to edit a cell changes the functional context of Excel. A lot of functionality is blocked while an edit action is performed. Just observe the ribbon when you change from cell navigation to cell editing (with F2 or whatever). Half the ribbon will become greyed out. The same applies behind the scenes for a lot of Excel API methods. It may cause all kinds of runtime errors to ignore this mode. You should prevent at all cost that users can do anything but wait for the end of your process. But be nice and keep them informed ;o)